How to apply a word paragraph (or text) style to text in a flextable cell?
Is there a way to format some text in a flextable cell with some word paragraph style? All cells seem to be formatted with "Normal" style (the standard paragraph style).
The manuals only handle visual/direct formatting of text. Something like mk_par(ft, j = 1, value = as_paragraph(as_chunk(col1data))) also seems to support only text formatting but no "logical" Word styles. The style() function that has an pr_p argument doesn't seem to work for flextables - at least in docx output.
Any other option?

No, there is no such option. flextable is supposed to give the same rendering for any format, so it can't rely only on a Word style table.
